# AS3 TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3

I (along with everyone else who posts a question here) am fairly new to `AS3`. So I am going crazy trying to figure out what is causing this error. I have a 'jukebox' player that loads songs accordingly when the button is clicked. BUT this is my error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at lesson09_V2_S5_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

And this is my code:

```
import fl.events.SliderEvent;

var snd:Sound;
var channel:SoundChannel;
var trans:SoundTransform;

//create variables to store values for the current song and it's volume and pan        settings.
var currSong:String;
var currVol:Number = .5;
var currPan:Number = 0;

// Array of all the songs in the current playlist.
var songList:Array=new Array("Nothing On You.mp3","Grenade.mp3","Ride.mp3","Pretty       Girl Rock.mp3","Tick Tock.mp3","Dynamite.mp3");

// don't need to see the volume and pan controls until a song is playing
panSlide.visible=false;
volSlide.visible=false;

   //Listeners for the onstage song buttons
song1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);
song6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseSong);

//listeners for the volume and pan sliders 
panSlide.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, panChange);
volSlide.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, volumeChange);


//sets the text field of all of the song buttons to display the names of the songs in      the songList array
for (var i = 0; i < songList.length; i++) {
    var str:String = songList[i] as String;
str = str.replace(".mp3","");
var clip = this["song" + (i + 1)].title;
clip.text = str;
  }

//switch statement to set the current song based on which song button was clicked.

function chooseSong(e:MouseEvent):void {
switch (e.currentTarget.name) {
    case "song1":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[0] as String;
        break;

    case "song2":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[1] as String;
        break;

    case "song3":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[2] as String;
        break;

    case "song4":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[3] as String;
        break;

    case "song5":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[4] as String;
        break;

    case "song6":
        currSong = "../MP3s/"+songList[5] as String;
        break;

if (snd != null) {
    channel.stop();
}
snd = new Sound();
snd.load(new URLRequest(currSong));
snd.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);

function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
// Do nothing
}
}
}
channel = new SoundChannel  ;
trans = new SoundTransform(currVol,currPan);
channel = snd.play();
channel.soundTransform = trans;
panSlide.visible = true;
volSlide.visible = true;
//currVolume and pan values are used here for display in the text fields next to    sliders

volLabel.text = "Current Volume " + int(currVol * 100);
panLabel.text = "Current Pan " + int(currPan * 100);

//listens for arrival of ID3 tags
snd.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler);
 //triggered when id3 tags are available
 //sets info text field to display current song information from id3 tags.
 function id3Handler(event:Event):void {
var id3:ID3Info = snd.id3;
if (id3.songName != null) {
    songTitle.text = id3.songName + "\n";
    info.text="Artist: \n"+id3.artist+"\n \n";
    info.appendText("Album: \n" + id3.album);
    info.appendText("\n\n" + "Available at: \n" + "passionrecords \n.com");
}
}


var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.font = "Arial Black";
format.color = 0xFFFF00;
format.size = 14;
format.url = "http://www.passionrecords.com/";

info.defaultTextFormat = format;
// uses volume slider value to control volume
function volumeChange(e:SliderEvent):void {
currVol = e.target.value;
volLabel.text = "Current Volume: " + int(currVol*100);
trans.volume = currVol;
channel.soundTransform = trans;
 }


 function panChange(e:SliderEvent):void {
currPan = e.target.value;
panLabel.text = "Current Pan " + int(currPan*100);
trans.pan = e.target.value;
channel.soundTransform = trans;
 }
```

Comment: If you start the application in debug mode then it should give you the line number for the error that will help you track down the problem. Also, it might just be an error copying the code here but you've got an error in your `chooseSong` function, move the `if` statement outside the `switch`.

Comment: thanks! I did fix that error but once that fixed I got a new one:     Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.at lesson09_V2_S5_fla::MainTimeline/chooseSong()[lesson09_V2_S5_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:73]                                 Any suggestions?

Comment: and line 73 with the error is:  snd = new Sound();

Comment: Can you update your code with the changes you made? Please make sure it's indented properly to make it easier to read. Have a look at this page for information on error #2032 http://curtismorley.com/2008/02/08/actionscript-error-2032/ The path to the mp3 is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct one..

line 73 with the error is: snd = new Sound();